# How to extend Symfony 3 Error Handling?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

I'm trying to extend the Symfony 3.3 built-in error handler in order to override what it does on the CLI, but leave the existing behavior in place for web requests.

Whenever I have a bug in my unit tests in Symfony, it spits out 3000 lines of HTML to the CLI. This is just silly.

So I've tried to following [the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/controller/error_pages.html#overriding-the-default-exceptioncontroller) for extending the built in error handling.

I added

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true

   twig.exception_listener:
       class:  AppBundle\Controller\MyExceptionController
       public: true
       arguments: "%kernel.debug%"
```

Like it shows on the docs, and Symfony complains:

`Type error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition::setArguments() must be of the type array, string given, called in /Projects/rest_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php on line 425`

So on another Stack Overflow page, I found you have to also pass in Twig.

Now I have this in services.yml

```
   twig.exception_listener:
       class:  AppBundle\Controller\MyExceptionController
       public: true
       arguments: ["@twig", "%kernel.debug%"]
```

So far so good. Here's MyExceptionController:

```html
<?php
// AppBundle/Controllers/MyExceptionController.php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FlattenException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\DebugLoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class MyExceptionController extends ExceptionController
{
    /**
     * Converts an Exception to a Response.
     *
     * A "showException" request parameter can be used to force display of an error page (when set to false) or
     * the exception page (when true). If it is not present, the "debug" value passed into the constructor will
     * be used.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param FlattenException $exception
     * @param DebugLoggerInterface|null $logger
     * @return Response
     */
    public function showAction(Request $request, FlattenException $exception, DebugLoggerInterface $logger = null)
    {
        if (php_sapi_name() === 'cli') {
            $error = <<<EOF
-------------------------------------------------------
--    ______ _____  _____   ____  _____  _ 
--   |  ____|  __ \|  __ \ / __ \|  __ \| |
--   | |__  | |__) | |__) | |  | | |__) | |
--   |  __| |  _  /|  _  /| |  | |  _  /| |
--   | |____| | \ \| | \ \| |__| | | \ \|_|
--   |______|_|  \_\_|  \_\\____/|_|  \_(_)
--                                         
--------------------------------------------------------
EOF;

            $error .= "\n".print_r($exception, true)."\n";
            return $error;
        } else {
            return parent::showAction($request, $exception, $logger);
        }
    }

}
```

Here's the weird thing. I get the default HTML error page in the browser, and HTML went away from the CLI, but I'm not seeing my code get called. Even if I put `die('Got Here')` at the top of my showAction() method, it never is called.

I went back and re-read the docs several times. I tried this:

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    exception_controller: AppBundle:MyExceptionController:showAction
```

Still nothing. It seemed to have no effect at all.

So what's going on wrong here?

Comment: why would you even try rendering twig it CLI? CLI is all about commands, controllers shouldn't be part of it.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you even try rendering twig it CLI? CLI is all about commands, controllers shouldn't be part of it and they can't be because there is no request/response but instead you have stdin and stdout.

If you want to have exception handler for commands then you should use [ConsoleEvents::ERROR](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/components/console/events.html). But this shouldn't be standard flow of the application, it's better to use try,catch,finally to actually catch exceptions and react accordingly